# User model won't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, ruby-1.9.3

I try to update an existing user:

**Controller-Snippet**

```
  def account_settings
    @user = current_user
  end

  def set_account_info
    old_user = current_user

    # verify the current password by creating a new user record.
    @user = User.authenticate_by_username(old_user.username, params[:user][:password])

    # verify
    if @user.nil?
      @user = current_user
      @user.errors[:password] = "Das eingegebene Passwort ist falsch."
      render :action => "account_settings"
    else
      # update the user with any new username and email
      @user.update(params[:user])
      # Set the old email and username, which is validated only if it has changed.
      @user.previous_email = old_user.email
      @user.previous_username = old_user.username

      if @user.valid?
        # If there is a new_password value, then we need to update the password.
        @user.password = @user.new_password unless @user.new_password.nil? || @user.new_password.empty?
        @user.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Benutzerkonto-Einstellungen wurden übernommen.'
        redirect_to :root
      else
        flash[:error] = @user.username
        render :action => "account_settings"
      end
    end
  end
```

I allready tried post-, put- and patch-method.

**Route-Snippet**

```
Calendar::Application.routes.draw do
  root "welcome#index"

  get "user/account_settings" => "user#account_settings"

  patch "user/account_settings" => "user#set_account_info"
end
```

**User-Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :previous_email, :previous_username, :password, :password_confirmation, :new_password, :new_password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password, :new_password, :previous_email, :previous_username
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_confirmation_of :new_password, :if => Proc.new {|user| !user.new_password.nil? && !user.new_password.empty? }
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email, :if => Proc.new {|user| user.previous_email.nil? || user.email != user.previous_email}
  validates_presence_of :username, :if => Proc.new {|user| user.previous_username.nil? || user.username != user.previous_username}
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :if => Proc.new {|user| user.previous_email.nil? || user.email != user.previous_email}
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :if => Proc.new {|user| user.previous_username.nil? || user.username != user.previous_username}

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super # must allow the active record to initialize!
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def self.authenticate_by_email(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def self.authenticate_by_username(username, password)
    user = find_by_username(username)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

The Flash-Notice `flash[:error] = @user.username` puts the new username, so I dont understand why the user isn't updated in the database.
First I thought my `set_account_info`-method isn't right, but I have no better idea how to check the inputs.
Secondly I changed the form_for method from default(post) to `put` and then to `patch`, but that also didn't help.

Comment: You have `ruby-on-rails-4` tag but you're using `attr_accessible` instead of strong params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With rails 4 attr_accessible is no longer used, instead we now have strong params. what this means is that you now need to tell the application what parameters it can update (A whitelist).

This is all done in the controller now, I will give you an example of what I do and see if it helps you in your scenario

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController

 def create
   @object= Object.new(my_params)
    if @object.save
     redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Object Successfully Created'
    else
     render action: 'new'
    end
end

def update
  @object= Object.find(params[:id])
    if @object.update_attributes(my_params)
     redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Object updated'
  else
    render action: 'edit'
  end
end

private

def my_params
params.require(:object).permit(:id, :title, :overview, :category_id, 
nested_attributes: [:id, :gallery_id, :gallery_category_id, :photo, :_destroy])

end
```

Comment: Oh well, that's new to me and I thought I could use the old function.