# Devise Unpermitted First and last name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i am currently trying to sign up/create an account for application using devise on ruby on rails(5.2.2) and ruby version 2.3.7 but i am getting the unpermitted parameter message and tried with Strong parms but it didn't work.

tried this two posts below but didn't work

[Rails 4 and Devise: Devise not saving new information (First Name, Last Name, Profile Name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257562/rails-4-and-devise-devise-not-saving-new-information-first-name-last-name-pr)

[Rails 4 and Devise: Devise not saving new information (First Name, Last Name, Profile Name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257562/rails-4-and-devise-devise-not-saving-new-information-first-name-last-name-pr)

```rb
class Api::V3::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  # before_filter :authenticate_user!
  private
  def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname,:lastname,:username,:password]) 

   # devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :provider
   # devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :uid
  end

end
```

> Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
>   Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"testuser@gmail.com",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "firstname"=>devise", "lastname"=>"test"}}
>   Unpermitted parameters: :firstname, :lastname

it looks like devise is not accepting parameters and which is resulting in first and last name not stored in local database.

Comment: Did you tried adding :firstname and :lastname in `sign_up_params` in your devise registration controller? you have to permit those in registration controller...

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan didn't do that how can i access devise registration controller or do i need to create a  registration controller that extends devise registration controller

Comment: `rails g devise:controller` will generate controllers for you.... or you can add a controller that extends devise registration controller

Answer (score 1):

You can override the registration controller and add fields you want.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

if resource.save
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords
  respond_with resource
end
end  
# you will get the full registration controller in devise github repo

 private

def sign_up_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

end
```

and add the new routes too

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
```

devise github repo [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

Comment: Thank you so much but i have a question do i need registration controller and application controller to be in same folder .Name of the file  is registration_controller.rb?

Comment: nope.... you can move the registration controller to a different folder inside controllers folder and rewrite the route as like `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations' }`

Comment: please do upvote and mark as answer if you got positive result for your questions

Comment: iam getting this error message  ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant RegistrationsController):

Comment: can you add your routes???? also add the controller first line line `class Devise::Registration......`